# Reducer checking action.type with indexOf

Tags: redux, react-redux

I wrote a redux reducer that helps me group error messages from other reducers.

I'm wondering if this could have any side effect since I don't see anyone doing it. I'm also wondering if there is a better way to do it that I couldn't think of.

This is what I wrote:

```
const errors = (state = {}, action = {}) => {

    let new_state = Object.assign({}, state);

    // if action type contains ERROR and action error is present
    if (action.type.indexOf("ERROR") != "-1" && action.error) {
        let error_id = Utils.hashCode(action.error);

        // if error already in the array
        if (new_state[error_id]) {
            new_state[error_id].count++;
        }

        // otherwise add the message to the list
        else {
            new_state[error_id] = {message: action.error, count: 1};
        }
    }

    // regular switch stmt
    switch (action.type) {
        case ERRORS_RESET: new_state = {}; break;
    }

    return new_state;
}
```

My store looks something like this now:

```
{
    reducer1: {
       something: [],
       error: "Some error message",
    },
    reducer2: {
       something: [],
       error: false,
    },
    reducer3: {
       some_other_obj: {},
       error: "Another error message",
    },
    errors: [
        {message: "Some error message, count: 1}
        {message: "Another error message", count: 2}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall concept of listening for `"SOMETHING_ERROR"` actions is fine, but there's a couple issues with your implementation.

First, your `if` statement has a direct mutation of the existing state.  Per the [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section of the Redux docs, you need to make sure you copy *every* level of nesting.  Right now you're copying the first level of the state, but not the nested object.

Second, you're *always* copying the state, even when there's nothing that's actually changed.  That's generally going to cause unnecessary re-renders in your UI.

Comment: Thanks! For the first point I still need to get the hang of it, mostly because I write reducers that only need to care about flat objects. For the second point that is something I have never thought about, it actually makes a lot of sense.